# FormView ConvertEmptyStringToNull and binding

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, .net-3.5, objectdatasource, formview

I'm using a FormView with an ObjectDataSource and binding using <%# Bind("WhateverProp") %> - and all of my nullable columns are coming back with default values of the type in them.

It appears that the FormView object doesn't have a ConvertEmtpyStringToNull property like the other binding containers do.  I've found articles suggesting that this was a bug in VS 2005 / .Net 2.0 - but don't see any saying what the resolution was.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can work around this without just re-capturing all of the fields in the ODS_Inserting event?  I'd rather not have to write code to re-bind all of my bound fields on the form just to test for nulls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Struggled with it too.
For a dropdownlist, I do that:

```
AppendDataBoundItems="true"


<asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
```

For my ObjectDataSource, even thoug my UpdateMethod takes a single parameter, the entity, I add Update params for each Nullable Field of the Entity with convert to NULL

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="No_Empl_Ferme" Type="Int32" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

I do the same for the Insert.

Works fine.

Comment: Just ran into this issue today - and re-read thru all of the answers again. Yours is defintely the most correct.  You CAN specify parameter names even when using the DataObjectTypeName property on the ODS.  Good answer - I've changed the marked answer to point to yours.

Comment: This also solves a similar issue whereby ObjectDataSource throws an exception if a bound textbox gets disabled on the client-side before being submitted. Adding an explicit parameter solved this.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing this - kind of a shotgun approach, but in this case *all* of my empty string values should be nulls.  I've also considered using a string array in the code to specify which values should be nulled - and then could just loop thru the string array instead of over all of the values.

```
protected void RequestItemFormView_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Values.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (e.Values[i].ToString() == string.Empty)
        {
            e.Values[i] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Object DataSource, you need to add InsertParameters for each of your nullable type with the Attribute ConvertEmtpyStringToNull="True" :

```
<InsertParameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="NullableFieldName" Type="Int32" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"  />            
</InsertParameters>
```

Comment: Tonio - i'm not using individual params, but DataObjectTypeName instead.  My insert method takes a single param, and that's the business object that I want to have saved back to the database.

Comment: Tonio - on a re-read - you were half there, so +1 for that.  @devMomentum has the more correct answer though, so he gets the marked answer.

Answer (score 1):

Quote:
Tonio - i'm not using individual params, but DataObjectTypeName instead. My insert method takes a single param, and that's the business object that I want to have saved back to the database. – Scott Ivey May 1 at 12:57

I've fixed it like this:

```
 protected void FormViewSettings_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {
     OrderedDictionary values = e.NewValues as OrderedDictionary;

     var personID = values["PersonID"];

     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(personID.ToString()))
     {
        values.Remove("PersonID");
        values.Add("PersonID", null);
     }
  }
```

It's a little hack but it works fine.
This way you can set the object property to null instead of string.empty without using the ConvertEmptyStringToNull setting.